# Integrating user acounts

Tags: imac, mojave, user-account

I bought a new iMac and migrated stuff over from my old mac. I now have 3 user accounts, 2 with different variations on my name! None of them access the same applications and information. I have no idea how I accomplished this: computers are not my strong suit. How do I blend them all together? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Each time do you a migration, it will make a new account on the new machine.

I can only assume to get 3 separate accounts you started with a brand new user on the new Mac, then did two separate, possibly partial, migrations.

It **is** possible to manually merge them, [I also learned the hard way how to do this] but in all honesty, & especially as you claim to not be a power-user, it will be simpler to wipe the Mac & start over. It may not actually take any longer than trying to merge what you have currently & is likely to be less 'hazardous'.
Do a full single migration as part of the initial setup. When the machine first asks you who you are, there is a point at which you migrate instead of making a new user.

Apple have a step by step procedure to "sell" your Mac & set up fresh for the "new owner". I would follow that. [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) As it reboots once more as a "new Mac" then follow the Migration guide - [How to move your content to a new Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204350) which should then Migrate to one single new account, matching the one you had on your previous machine.